# How to fix 'Failed to convert the JSON string 'varchar(2)' to a data type.'

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, varchar

We want to move from spark 3.0.1 to 3.1.2. According to migration guide varchar data types are now supported in table schema. Unfortunately data onboarded with new version cant be queried by old spark versions which considered varchar as a string in table schema. According to [migration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/sql-migration-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-30-to-31) applying `spark.sql.legacy.charVarcharAsString` to `true` in Spark Session configuration should do the trick but we still get varchar datatype instead of string in hive table schema.

As is:
[image]

To be:
[image]

What are we missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade spark version according to this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37452. There is a bug which affect versions 3.1.2, 3.2.0. And it was fixed in versions 3.1.3, 3.2.1, 3.3.0